Why did they not wear space suits in "Alien: Covenant" after their crew was obviously getting sick?
In Alien: Covenant (2017), let's say it makes sense that no one was wearing a mask, which would have prevented infections. Why did they not wear space suits after their crew was obviously getting sick?

My theory is that the colony ship is actually the dregs of humanity, sent to the stars as a sort of expensive test flight before they send the actual colony ship. That would explain why everyone is terrible at their jobs and keeps making irrational, incompetent decisions
